# get cell background c# google spreadsheet

Tags: asp.net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to read data from google spreadsheet using asp.net

I want to get cell background color and the comment of this cell.
any idea?
also, is there a way to address a cell like an excel cell property that you can get;set all his attributes?

thanks,
Moshe

Answer (score 1):

To receive the background-color you need to "IncludeGridData" on your "Get" request

In C# this is attached to the request Object.

```
SpreadsheetsResource.GetRequest request = sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Get(spreadsheetId);
request.Ranges = ranges;
request.IncludeGridData = true;
Data.Spreadsheet response = request.Execute();
```

A good documentation with examples for many languages can be found at: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [reading data guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading_a_single_range)

Reading a single range

To read a single range of data out of a spreadsheet, use a spreadsheets.values.get request:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/range
```

Use the [.NET Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) for your reference.

Comment: I didn't manage to use this get link. because when I work in the server side I use c# like the .NET quickstart you sent, I'm already using it.
How should I use the GET in the c# code?